# Which one should I use exit, error or throw?

Tags: erlang

Could you tell me when to use `throw`, `exit` and `error`?

```erlang
1> catch throw ({aaa}).
{aaa}
2> catch exit ({aaa}).
{'EXIT',{aaa}}
3> catch gen_server:call(aaa,{aaa}).
{'EXIT',{noproc,{gen_server,call,[aaa,{aaa}]}}}
4> catch exit("jaj")
{'EXIT',"jaj"}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are **3** classes which can be caught with a `try ... catch`: `throw`, `error` and `exit`.

- `throw` is generated using `throw/1` and is intended to be used for *non-local returns* and does not generate an error unless it is not caught (when you get a `nocatch` error).
- `error` is generated when the system detects an error. You can explicitly generate an error using `error/1`. The system also includes a stacktrace in the generated error value, for example `{badarg,[...]}`.
- `exit` is generated using `exit/1` and is intended to signal that this process is to die.

The difference between `error/1` and `exit/1` is not that great, it more about intention which the stacktrace generated by errors enhances.

The difference between them is actually more noticeable when doing `catch ...`: when `throw/1` is used then the `catch` just returns the thrown value, as is expected from a non-local return; when an `error/1` is used then the `catch` returns `{'EXIT',Reason}` where `Reason` contains the stacktrace; while from `exit/1` `catch` also returns `{'EXIT',Reason}` but `Reason` only contains the actual exit reason. `try ... catch` looks like it equates them, but they are/were very different.

Comment: @ChenYu - apologies for my sloppy explanation. rvirding - thanks for clearing that up. Let me either fix/delete my answer - lesser confusion the better!

Answer (score 7):

**[UPDATED]**

*I glossed over the important difference between **throw** and **error**, pointed out by Robert Virding. This edit is just for the record!*

<s>throw</s> `error` is to be used where one would use `throw` in other languages. An error in a running process has been detected by your code, which signals an exception with `error/1`. The same process catches it (possibly higher up in the stack), and the error is to be handled within the same process. `error` always brings with it a stacktrace.

`throw` is to be used not to signal an error, but just to return a value from a deeply nested function.
Since it unwinds the stack, calling `throw` returns the thrown value to the place it was caught.  As in the case of `error`, we're catching stuff that was thrown, only what was thrown wasn't an error but rather just a value passed up the stack. This is why throw does not bring with it a stacktrace.

As a contrived example, if we wanted to implement an `exists` function for lists, (similar to what `list:any` does) and as an exercise without doing the recursing ourselves, and using just `list:foreach`, then `throw` could be used here:

```
exists(P, List) ->
  F = fun(X) -> 
    case P(X) of 
      true -> throw(true); 
      Whatever -> Whatever 
    end
  end,
  try lists:foreach(F, List) of
    ok -> false
  catch
   true -> true
  end.
```

A value thrown but not caught is treated as an `error`: a `nocatch` exception will be generated.

EXIT is to be signaled by a process when it *'gives up'*.  The ***parent*** process handles the EXIT, while the child process just dies. This is the Erlang let-it-crash philosophy.

So `exit/1`'s EXIT is not to be caught within the same process, but left to the parent. `error/1`'s errors are local to the process - i.e., a matter of what happens and how it is handled *by the process itself*; `throw/1` is used for control flow across the stack.

**[UPDATE]**

1. This tutorial explains it well: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions
2. Note there is also a `exit/2` - called with a *`Pid`* of a process to send the EXIT to.
   `exit/1` implies the parent process.

Comment: @ChenYu If you read the chapter you will see that the explanation here is wrong. You use `throw/1` to do a non-local return, **NOT** for throwing an error, you use `error/1` for signalling an error and you `exit/1` for showing that the process is to die. There are **3** types of classes: `throw`, `error` and `exit`

Comment: @rvirding hope I've made amends with this. Feedback appreciated!

Comment: @Faiz Yes, that's fine. :-) There is one subtle difference between `exit(foo)` and `exit(self(),foo)` which very many miss. The `exit/1` version is "internal" to the process and can be caught with `try/catch` while `exit/2` is "external" and actually sends the signal to itself so it can't be caught with `try/catch` but trapping exists converts it to a message as with any other exit signal. Even the BEAM doesn't get it completely right. There is a bug report about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Erlang, but here's how I think about what these things are, their differences, what they're used for, etc.:

`throw`: a condition that should be handled locally (i.e. within the current process). E.g. caller is looking for an element in a collection, but does not know if the collection actually contains such an element; then, the callee could throw if such an element is not present, and the caller detect absence by using `try[/of]/catch`. If caller neglects to do this, then this gets turned into an `nocatch` `error` (explained below).

`exit`: The current process is done. E.g. it has simply finished (in that case, you'd pass `normal`, which is treated the the same as the original function returning), or its operation was cancelled (E.g. it normally loops indefinitely but has just received a `shut_down` message).

`error`: the process has done something and/or reached a state that the programmer did not take into account (E.g. 1/0), believes is impossible (E.g. `case ... of` encounters a value that does not match any case), or some precondition is not met (E.g. input is nonempty). In this case, local recovery doesn't make sense. Therefore, neither `throw` nor `exit` is appropriate. Since this is unexpected, a stack trace is part of the Reason.

As you can see, the above list is in escalating order:

`throw` is for sane conditions that the caller is expected to handle. I.e. handling occurs *within* the current process.

`exit` is also sane, but should end the current process simply because the process is done.

`error` is insane. Something happened that can't reasonably be recovered from (usually a bug?), and local recovery would not be appropriate.

---

vs. other languages:

`throw` is analogous to the way checked exceptions are used in Java. Whereas, `error` is used in a manner more analogous to unchecked exceptions. Checked exceptions are exceptions you want the caller to handle. Java requires you to either wrap calls in `try/catch` or declare that your method `throws` such exceptions. Whereas, unchecked exceptions generally propagate to the outermost caller.

`exit` does not have a good analog in more "conventional" languages like Java, C++, Python, JavaScript, Ruby, etc. `exit` vaguely like an uber-`return`: instead of returning at the end, you can return from the middle of a function, except you don't just return from the current function, you return from them ALL.

---

`exit` Example

```
serve_good_times() ->
  receive
    {top_of_the_mornin, Sender} ->
      Sender ! and_the_rest_of_the_day_to_yourself;
    {you_suck, Sender} ->
      Sender ! take_a_chill_pill;
    % More cases...

    shut_down ->
      exit(normal)
  end,
  serve_good_times()
end
```

Since `serve_good_times` calls itself after almost all messages, the programmer has decided that we don't want to repeat that call in every receive case. Therefore, she has put that call *after* the receive. But then, what if `serve_good_times` decides to stop calling itself? This is where `exit` comes to the rescue. Passing `normal` to `exit` causes the process to terminate just as though the last function call has returned.

As such, it's generally inappropriate to call `exit` in a general purpose library, like `lists`. It's none of the library's business whether the process should end; that should be decided by application code.

---

What About Abnormal `exit`?

This matters if another process (the "remote" process) is linked to the "local" process that calls `exit` (and `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` was not called): Just like the last function returning, `exit(normal)` does not cause remote process to exit. But if the local process makes a `exit(herp_derp)` call, then the remote process also exits with `Reason=herp_derp`. Of course, if the remote process is linked to yet more processes, they also get exit signal with `Reason=herp_derp`. Therefore, non-`normal` exits result in a chain reaction.

Let's take a look at this in action:

```
1> self().   
<0.32.0>
2> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(normal) end).
<0.35.0>
3> self().
<0.32.0>
4> 
4> 
4> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(abnormal) end).
** exception exit: abnormal
5> self().
<0.39.0>
6>
```

The first process that we spawned did not cause the shell to exit (we can tell, because `self` returned the same pid before and after `spawn_link`). BUT the second process did cause the shell to exit (and the system replaced the shell process with a new one).

Of course, if the remote process uses `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` then it just gets a message, regardless of whether the local process passes `normal` or something else to `exit`. Setting this flag stops the chain reaction.

```
6> process_flag(trap_exit, true).
false
7> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(normal) end).  
<0.43.0>
8> self().
<0.39.0>
9> flush().
Shell got {'EXIT',<0.43.0>,normal}
ok
10>                                         
10> 
10> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(abnormal) end).
<0.47.0>
11> self(). 
<0.39.0>
12> flush().
Shell got {'EXIT',<0.47.0>,abnormal}
```

Recall that I said that `exit(normal)` is treated like the original function returning:

```
13> spawn_link(fun() -> ok end).
<0.51.0>
14> flush().
Shell got {'EXIT',<0.51.0>,normal}
ok
15> self().
<0.39.0>
```

What do you know: the same thing happened as when `exit(normal)` was called. Wonderful!

Comment: btw, exit(self(), wat) is NOT equivalent to exit(wat). The two behave differently when process_flag(trap_exit, true) is in use (by the current thread): the former results in an 'EXIT' message; whereas, the latter really does exit right there and then.

Comment: Also if you do exit(NotSelf, reason) and NotSelf is using trap_exit, then it gets a message rather than exiting, just as though a remote (from the perspective of NotSelf) had exitted. To me, this is really unintuitive; I thought that trap_exit only pertained to remote processes exiting, but it also applies to self when exited using exit/2, even when called by self()! My brain (and my feelings) hurts right now...

Comment: Another thing I didn't realize about {'EXIT', Pid, Reason} messages when they are generated by exit/2: Pid is the process that calls exit/2, not the process named by the first argument of exit/2. Crazy...

Comment: For {'EXIT',Pid,Reason}, please check it again. I remember when a pid is terminiated, all linked pid will received this message (if it trap exit). Maybe your pid kills itself.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I said. The part where I was confused is what does Pid refer to? In the case of remote linked process exiting for whatever reason, Pid is that of the exiting process. In the case of exit/2, it is not the process being exited. It is the remote process. That's the common thread between the two ways of getting 'EXIT': Pid is that of the remote process.